# How to get refresh token in MSAL .Net C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-msal

I have identified two approaches for acquiring token in MSAL for EWS

1. Using Username Password approach.
2. Using Daemon Confidential approach.

In both above approached after I acquire token, I am not able to refresh it. Though I tried to follow MS docs but no success. GetAccountsAsync() always gives empty result.

Here is my Code for Username Password approach

```
var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                 .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantId).Build();
var accounts = publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result = publicClientApplication
                 .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                 .ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Can anyone guide me why it is happening so, or is there doc explaining this flow.

Comment: It could be the default token cache is not working for your scenario. You might need to implement a properly persisting token cache that the MSAL app object would use to store the accounts and tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> MSAL maintains a token cache and caches a token after it has been acquired. It's also capable of refreshing a token when it's getting close to expiration (as the **token cache also contains a refresh token**).

**MSAL.NET does not expose refresh tokens**, for security reasons: MSAL handles refreshing tokens for you with token cache.

As you `GetAccountsAsync()` always get empty, did your [Token Cache serialization](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization#token-cache-for-a-web-app-confidential-client-application).

By default, access tokens expire after 1h, and if AAD is busy when the tokens expire, your application will become unavailable because you cannot acquire a valid access token. You can improve the availability of your application by regularly [**forcing a refresh**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/High-availability#pro-active-token-renewal). We recommend to force a refresh every 30 min, or half the lifetime of the AT when this is a custom lifetime.

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
             .WithForceRefresh(true)
             .ExecuteAsync();
```